# Twitter api library

Tags: php

I use [Abraham Williams Twitter OAuth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) for my application. But I have issues on uploading files. I checked from Twitter API that TmhOAuth has support for file uploading. Does Abraham Williams Twitter OAuth library support for file upload?

Comment: Uploads don't really have much to do with the OAuth part of the API, beyond needing an OAuth permission token.

Answer (score 0):

Check the other popular ones, I know a couple of them support uploads: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php